# Using the Sanity client without specifying an API version is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, api, content-management-system, sanity

I am getting this warning in the console and could not able to clearly understand the documentation.

> warnings.js:16 Using the Sanity client without specifying an API version is deprecated. See https://docs.sanity.io/help/js-client-api-version

I would like it to always have the latest API version. Here is how my connection looks like

```
import santiyClient from "@sanity/client";

export default santiyClient({
  projectId: "myProjectID",
  dataset: "production",
  useCdn: true,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify an API version when you configure your client:

```
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";

export default sanityClient({
  projectId: "myProjectID",
  dataset: "production",
  useCdn: true,
  apiVersion: "2022-02-03"
});
```

It's best to hard code your API version to the date you implement it. That way, it's guaranteed to work as you expect. If you were to use a JavaScript Date to always return whatever *today* is, a breaking change could be put in place that causes the client to no longer work. There are a few more details in the documentation [here](https://www.sanity.io/help/js-client-api-version).

Answer (score 0):

You should also create token and pass the token:

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client'

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: 'projectId',
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2021-03-25',
  token: 'click API tab and add new token',
  useCdn: false,
})
```